# How to position a rotated element in the middle on the right?

Tags: html, css

I need to position a rotated element in the middle of the page on the right site. The centering works fine without the rotation but with the rotation it messes everything up because the width of the element I need to rotate is not defined.

```css
#text-right {
 right: 0;
 -moz-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Firefox 3.6 Firefox 4 */
 -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Safari */
 -o-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Opera */
 -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* IE9 */
 transform: rotate(90deg); /* W3C */
  }

.side-text {
 position: fixed;
 top: 50%;

 -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="text-right" class="side-text">
  <a href="some link" class="navigation" draggable="false">
    <h1>Grafik im Raum</h1>
  </a>
</div>
```

How can I center it in the middle and on the right site?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to set a suitable `transform-origin` point (I used top right) and based on that adjust the translation accordingly.

Remember `translateX` still relates to the width of the element even though it's rotated.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#text-right {
  right: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
}
.side-text {
  background: lightblue;
  transform-origin: top right;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="text-right" class="side-text">
  <a href="some link" class="navigation" draggable="false">
    <h1>Grafik im Raum</h1>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: This works fine for a right positioned element. Now I also need one for the left but changing the transform-origin to top left doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Okay I changed the -90deg to 270deg and now it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I centered the texts parent div first, centered the text inside using text-align and vertical-align, and rotated the text inside.

```
#text-right {
    height: 100px;
    width: 400px;
    right: 0;
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Firefox 3.6 Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Safari */
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Opera */
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* IE9 */
    transform: rotate(90deg); /* W3C */
  }

.side-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-left: -200px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: center;
}    
<div id="text-right" class="side-text">
  <a href="some link" class="navigation" draggable="false">
    <h1>Grafik im Raum</h1>
  </a>
</div>
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/kz2gb0ox/

Answer (score 0):

Both your css selectors matches the same element, that's why only one transform is applied (rotate(90deg) is applied, translateY(-50%) isn't). But you can chain transforms! So solution to your problem will look like this:

```css
#text-right {
 right: 0;
  }

.side-text {
 position: fixed;
 top: 50%;

 -moz-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(90deg);
 -ms-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(90deg);
 -o-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(90deg);
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(90deg);
 transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="text-right" class="side-text">
  <a href="some link" class="navigation" draggable="false">
    <h1>Grafik im Raum</h1>
  </a>
</div>
```